# gopher-lua Pass struct and access fields from lua script function

Tags: go, lua

I just started using gopher-lua and seems it is interesting. But I can not figure out a way to pass a go struct and access its fields from a lua script. Can someone help me with this I can pass strings numbers using CallByParam want to find a way to do the same with a struct.

Thanks

Comment: Can someone please help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You need to use Lua Tables to do this.